# Get environment variable in PHP script

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, virtualhost

In my Apache (2.2) virtualHost configuration, I'd like to pipe my error log elsewhere.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ....

   SetEnv toPhp hello
   ErrorLog "|php /var/www/error.php >>/var/www/logs/vialora.log"

  ....

</VirtualHost>
```

However, while the `toPhp` variable is now available in the site this virtualhost is for, it is missing in `error.php`. How do I access this enviroment variable, assuming its value is dynamic?

Comment: so `echo $_SERVER["toPhp"]` doesn't show anything? What's your error.php like?

Comment: `$stdin = fopen ('php://stdin', 'r'); ob_implicit_flush (true); var_dump(phpinfo()); `, which nicely var_dumps phpinfo(), but the toPhp value is not set.

Comment: Are any Server vars available in the phpinfo() output? Or is PHP effectively being called from the command line via in ErrorLog entry in the vhost config? Even then, if I do a manual `export toPhp=hello` followed by a `php /srv/site/phpinfo.php | grep toPhp`, I still see the toPhp is set in $_SERVER

Comment: Yes, these are set: APACHE_PID_FILE, APACHE_RUN_USER, PATH, _, PWD, LANG, APACHE_RUN_GROUP, SHLVL, PHP_SELF, SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_FILENAME, PATH_TRANSLATED, DOCUMENT_ROOT, REQUEST_TIME, argv, argc. I was hoping to find a way to pass the value of an env. variable and read it from argv, but putting the variable in to ErrorLog directive passes it as a string, not the variable value.

Comment: Have you tried putting the value in your apache config envvars file?

Comment: How would I get dynamic values from there?

Comment: Hmmmm, yeah - envvars are available to the apache process, but not passed through to PHP

Answer (score 0):

From my virtual host I set:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then from a PHP script inside this virtual host I write:

```
// Display errors (just in case)
ini_set("display_errors", E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') ||
        define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

Working like a charm.

Comment: Problem is: the called php script isn't handled like it is in the virtual host.